# Rolling number animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I want to create a rolling number animation on a winning score

But I don't know how to make it!

I want to increase the target number from 0 to 1, or from 1 to 2 etc., only when the game won

js:

```js
let firstTarget = 0;
```

jsx:

```
<div
    style={{ backgroundColor: gameLost ? failureOp : gameWon ? successOp : 'lightgray' }}
    ref={firstNodeRef}
    className="inner-target-child"
>
    <div id="counter" className="animated">
        <ul className="digits luckie">
            <li>{firstTarget}</li>
            <li>{firstTarget + 1}</li>
            <li>{firstTarget + 2}</li>
            <li>{firstTarget + 3}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
#counter {
   height: 1em;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.digits {
   float:center;
   list-style-type: none;
   font-size: 1em;
   line-height: 1em;
   margin-top: 0em;

   animation-duration: 2s;
   animation-timing-function: ease;
   animation-delay: 2.2s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.luckie {
   animation-name: luckie;
}

/* Animations */
@keyframes luckie {
   100% {
       margin-top: -3em;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Z-Template is a client-side JavaScript library for dynamic HTML rendering with a syntax that combines dynamic variables, conditionals, and loops. It is MIT licensed. With this library you can include provided MIT covered zcall.roller.js that does the job.

If you use the whole library it is as easy as

```
<script type="text/javascript">zTemplate(document.querySelector('h1'), {"counter": 582});</script>
<h1 z-var="counter call roller">000</h1>
```

https://codepen.io/webdevelopers/full/vYabQNL

Or just sneak peak into that code library: https://github.com/webdevelopers-eu/z-template/tree/master/javascript/extra